# Complex Aggregation: three columns into the two columns with number of events

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, aggregate

For my short paper, I need to make a network analysis of terrorism. To perform this analysis I have to first form existing data to a more pleasant look. 
Task is to perform aggregation on `gname, gname2, gname3` with sum of `nkill` and count of identical attacks per year in the column of `n_attacks`. so if two events are in the same year by the same group twice the `n_attacks` would be 2.

**INPUT DATA**

```
|    |   iyear | gname                                                        | gname2                                    | gname3                                    |   nkill |
|---:|--------:|:-------------------------------------------------------------|:------------------------------------------|:------------------------------------------|--------:|
|  0 |    2017 | Lashkar-e-Jhangvi                                            | Tehrik-i-Taliban Pakistan (TTP)           | Aalmi Majlis-i-Tahfuz-i-Khatam-i-Nubuwaat |       1 |
|  1 |    2010 | Indian Mujahideen                                            | Students Islamic Movement of India (SIMI) | 313 Brigade                               |      17 |
|  2 |    2011 | Zeliangrong United Front                                     | Zeliangrong United Front                  | nan                                       |       7 |
|  3 |    2015 | National Socialist Council of Nagaland-Khaplang (NSCN-K)     | Zeliangrong United Front                  | nan                                       |       2 |
|  4 |    2008 | Communist Party of Nepal- Unified Marxist-Leninist (CPN-UML) | Young Communist League                    | nan                                       |       1 |
|  5 |    2015 | Abu Sayyaf Group (ASG)                                       | Waning Abdusalam Group (WAG)              | nan                                       |       4 |
|  6 |    2015 | Abu Sayyaf Group (ASG)                                       | Waning Abdusalam Group (WAG)              | nan                                       |       6 |
|  7 |    2015 | Baba Ladla Gang                                              | Uzair Baloch Gang                         | nan                                       |       7 |
|  8 |    2014 | Taliban                                                      | Tehrik-i-Taliban Pakistan (TTP)           | nan                                       |      24 |
```

[CSV](https://pastebin.com/2HgtvVat)

**EXAMPLE OUTPUT**

```
|    |   iyear | source                                                       | target                                    |   nkill |   n_attacks |
|---:|--------:|:-------------------------------------------------------------|:------------------------------------------|--------:|------------:|
|  0 |    2017 | Lashkar-e-Jhangvi                                            | Tehrik-i-Taliban Pakistan (TTP)           |       1 |           1 |
|  1 |    2010 | Indian Mujahideen                                            | Students Islamic Movement of India (SIMI) |      17 |           1 |
|  2 |    2011 | Zeliangrong United Front                                     | Zeliangrong United Front                  |       7 |           1 |
|  3 |    2015 | National Socialist Council of Nagaland-Khaplang (NSCN-K)     | Zeliangrong United Front                  |       2 |           1 |
|  4 |    2008 | Communist Party of Nepal- Unified Marxist-Leninist (CPN-UML) | Young Communist League                    |       1 |           1 |
|  5 |    2015 | Abu Sayyaf Group (ASG)                                       | Waning Abdusalam Group (WAG)              |      10 |           2 |
|  6 |    2015 | Baba Ladla Gang                                              | Uzair Baloch Gang                         |       7 |           1 |
|  7 |    2014 | Taliban                                                      | Tehrik-i-Taliban Pakistan (TTP)           |      24 |           1 |
|  8 |    2017 | Aalmi Majlis-i-Tahfuz-i-Khatam-i-Nubuwaat                    | Lashkar-e-Jhangvi                         |       1 |           1 |
|  9 |    2017 | Aalmi Majlis-i-Tahfuz-i-Khatam-i-Nubuwaat                    | Tehrik-i-Taliban Pakistan (TTP)           |       1 |           1 |
| 10 |    2010 | 313 Brigade                                                  | Students Islamic Movement of India (SIMI) |      17 |           1 |
| 11 |    2010 | 313 Brigade                                                  | Indian Mujahideen                         |      17 |           1 |
```

where 
iyear = year of the event(s);

source = source terrorist group;
 target = ally terrorist group;
 nkill = number of victims in the terrorist attack(s);
 n_attacks = number of attacks performed by source and target in the same year.

The problem is that I do not know how to perform such operation using Pandas. I thought about just for loop and semi-manually doing aggregation, but honestly I do not know. Any tips or code snippets would be helpful. Thanks.

UPD:
**REPRODUCIBLE EXAMPLE**

```
|    |   year | gname   | gname2   | gname3   |   nkill |
|---:|-------:|:--------|:---------|:---------|--------:|
|  0 |   1991 | A       | B        | C        |       3 |
|  1 |   1991 | C       | A        | nan      |       1 |
|  2 |   1991 | B       | C        | nan      |       2 |
|  3 |   1991 | D       | A        | B        |       5 |
```

**SAMPLE OUTPUT**

```
year | source | target | nkill   | n_attacks
1991 |    A   |   B    |    8    |    2
1991 |    B   |   C    |    5    |    2
1991 |    C   |   A    |    4    |    2
1991 |    D   |   A    |    5    |    1
etc...
```

Comment: took me more time to adapt your sample data so it could be slurped into a `df`... ;-)

Comment: thank you very much! but I attached CSV file, aha.

Comment: cool, hadn't seen it. For future reference, it's better to make a  [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example): you could have filled a small `df` with short words `'foo'`, `'bar'`, etc. It's always better if you can make things very concise (but not _so concise_ that you lose what the problem you're trying to solve is).

Comment: what is a "source" and what is a "target", and how can you tell the difference? In your updated example, `'A'`, `'B'` and `'C'` appear in either column. Also: row 0 seems to contribute to both `A, B` and `B, C` in the sample output. Intentional? Why not `C, B` and `B, A` too? Is it the case that you want all _2-combinations_ (`gname, gname2` and `gname2, gname3`)?

Comment: I tried to infer what you mean and updated my answer accordingly. However I see a difference against your new "SAMPLE OUTPUT". Why would `C, A` have values `4, 2`? Where do those come from? Do you actually want all the _2-permutations_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Modified answer**, based on the updated question

Ok, based on the updated example with sample data, I finally figured out what the OP wanted: a 2-permutation of all 3 `gname` columns.

```py
from itertools import permutations

combos = [{x: 'source', y: 'target', z: 'ignored'} for x, y, z in permutations('gname gname2 gname3'.split())]
out = pd.concat([df.rename(columns=mapper) for mapper in combos]).groupby(
    ['iyear', 'source', 'target']
)['nkill'].agg([sum, 'count']).rename(
    columns={'sum':'nkill', 'count':'n_attacks'})
```

Result (`out`) on the smaller sample input:

```
                     nkill  n_attacks
iyear source target                  
1991  A      B           8          2
             C           4          2
             D           5          1
      B      A           8          2
             C           5          2
             D           5          1
      C      A           4          2
             B           5          2
      D      A           5          1
             B           5          1
```

(Note for the purists: why not the more precise `... for x, y in permutations(..., r=2)`? Because then we'd end up with one of the `gname` columns not renamed, and the `concat` becomes messier with remaining `gname` columns left in -- it would work just the same, but the `concat` is wider).

**Initial answer** (for initial question...)

Try this:

```py
df.fillna('').groupby(
    'iyear gname gname2 gname3'.split()
)['nkill'].agg([sum, 'count'])
```

Output:

```
                                                                      sum  count
iyear gname                gname2               gname3                          
2008  Communist Party o... Young Communist L...                         1      1
2010  Indian Mujahideen    Students Islamic ... 313 Brigade            17      1
2011  Zeliangrong Unite... Zeliangrong Unite...                         7      1
2014  Taliban              Tehrik-i-Taliban ...                        24      1
2015  Abu Sayyaf Group ... Waning Abdusalam ...                        10      2
      Baba Ladla Gang      Uzair Baloch Gang                            7      1
      National Socialis... Zeliangrong Unite...                         2      1
2017  Lashkar-e-Jhangvi    Tehrik-i-Taliban ... Aalmi Majlis-i-Ta...    1      1
```

Explanations:

- the `.fillna('')` is because you have NaNs in your otherwise text column;
- the `groupby(...)` is simply expressing what you wanted;
- `.agg()` accepts multiple aggregations on one or several columns.

PS: BTW, you can rename the columns to your precise specs, as you surely know, by adding: `.rename(columns={'sum':'nkill', 'count':'n_attacks'})`.

Comment: I need to aggregate for two columns, not three. Dunno how to explain. There should be a source and target columns. This is a hard part that I don't know how to achieve. So gname1 gname2 gname3 convert just to source and target columns. This is essential for network analysis as nodes need to be connected to respect to just two columns, I think. Output example shows that I want to achieve.

Comment: added simple example in the post

Comment: is there any way to also include gname with empty values in gname2 and gname3? value for target would be identical with value of source. so: if gname2 is empty, but gname is not empty, then source and target would be gname value. ex: https://pastebin.com/ZzdcerbV